# Having issues with ASP.NET web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies, web-config

I'm facing a problem with two ASP.NET web pages. Those pages are hosted on the same server but in different application pools. Everytime I'm logged into page A, I'm facing a blank page when opening page B. It doesn't matter if I open it in a different tab or a new browser window, it shows me nothing.

So when testing the other way around, logging in at page B and then opening page A, it works fine BUT I'm already logged in at page A too (both pages use the same database and users). So it appears to me that I'm having a session/cookie problem here. I tried to define separate cookie names in the system.web section on both web configs already, unfortunately with no success.

Config SiteA:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <sessionState timeout="60" cookieName="SiteA"/>
    ...
  </system.web>
  ...
</configurtation>
```

Config SiteB:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <sessionState timeout="60" cookieName="SiteB"/>
    ...
  </system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: May be just use database sessionState?

Comment: what's the advantage?

Comment: Do these different sites have different urls / domains? I assume when you use the word "Page" you mean "Site"?

Comment: @Chris Reingruber: If you use in-memory session, and two requests from same browser end up in two application pools, the later one wont find the session created by the first one. But if it is database session, it will.

Comment: You login to A and expect What to happen when browsing B? Login page? Or the default page where the user is logged in? You can set the [Path property of authentication cookie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.formscookiepath(v=vs.110).aspx) but nothing similar can be done for the session as far as I know

Comment: I would expect to land at the login page so it'd be possible to login with different users

Comment: It's almost certainly not a session state conflict--as @mshsayem noted, it's not being shared (and it wouldn't be shared if you used a DB to store session state, either--ASP.NET keeps sessions from different sites/apps in different database rows). If you're using Forms authentication, I'd start by looking there for problems. The same auth cookie is being sent to both sites, so try changing the cookie name in the [<forms>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61(v=vs.100).aspx) element's `name` attribute.

Comment: @MarkWaterman thanks for this hint... it appears to me that this solves the problem! I'll test it a little bit further and get back to you later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the helping commentators on my question. The solution was the naming of the forms authentication cookies of both sites. After that it works fine. Thanks